# How can I get Vue to correctly update data dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, frontend, vue-component

The component I have below allows a user to view a products macro nutrient info and then also modify the serving size which in return updates the macro nutrient amounts.

The issue I'm having is that Im not getting the values to be updated correctly even when using vue set.

I'm using a watcher to run the calcNewNutriValues function.

```html
<template>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="left">
                <p class="left__name">{{ product.name }}</p>
                <p class="left__energy">{{ product.energy }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <button class="cancel" @click="removeItem">
                    <inline-svg
                        :src="require('../assets/svg/addition-icon.svg')"
                    ></inline-svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="macros">
                <p class="details__heading">Macros</p>
                <div class="macros__container container">
                    <div class="wrapper" v-for="(macro, name, index) in product.macros" :key="index">
                        <p>{{ name }}</p>
                        <p>{{ product.macros[name] }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="serving">
                <p class="details__heading">Serving Size (g)</p>
                <input type="number" placeholder="40" v-model.number="productServSize">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            productServSize: 0,
            ogServSize: 0,
            macros: {
                protein: '',
                carbs: '',
                fats: '',
                fibre: ''
            },
            micros: {},
            energy: ''
        }
    },

    props: [
        'product',
    ],

    methods: {
        serving () {
            const num = this.product.servingSize.split(' ')[0]
            this.productServSize = parseFloat(num)
            this.ogServSize = parseFloat(num)
        },

        removeItem () {
            this.$emit('removeProduct', this.product)
        },

        calcNewNutriValues () {
            Object.keys(this.product.macros).forEach(key => {
                let num = parseFloat(this.product.macros[key].split(' ')[0])
                let perGram = parseFloat(num / this.ogServSize)
                let newTotal = `${(perGram * this.productServSize).toFixed(1)} g`
                this.$set(this.macros, key, newTotal)
            })
        }
    },

    mounted () {
        this.serving()
        Object.assign(this.macros, this.product.macros)
        this.energy = this.product.energy
    },

    watch: {
        productServSize: {
            handler () {
                this.calcNewNutriValues()
                this.$emit('updatedNutriValues', this.product)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you create a minimal reprodusable example on codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: you might just want to make `this.macros` a `computed` property rather than a data property. instead of calling set, just use a return statement there.

Comment: You're never displaying anything from `this.macros`. The only displayed data is from `product.macros`. Since `product` is a prop, it seems the parent component should be handling an event from this component when the `productServSize` changes to update the macros

Answer (score 1):

It only seems like `macros` isn't updating because your template displays `product.macros` instead of `macros`:

```html
<div class="wrapper" v-for="(macro, name, index) in product.macros" :key="index"> 
  <p>{{ name }}</p>
  <!-- <p>{{ product.macros[name] }}</p>  DON'T DO THIS -->
  <p>{{ macros[name] }}</p>
</div>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-driscoll-7p0n9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FProduct.vue&theme=dark)